# Get the operation type inside a "Insert or Update" trigger

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

Can we capture inside a `Insert or Update` trigger that this triggers has been executed because of `Insert` or due to an `Update` statement?

One way to know this is to make separate triggers for both `Insert` and `Update`

But it would be very nice if I can do this inside one trigger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Conditional Predicates](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS750) INSERTING/UPDATING/DELETING inside the trigger to determine 
which DML fired the trigger.

Sample trigger:

```
create trigger sample_trigger
    before insert or update
    on sample_table
    for each row
begin
    case
        when inserting then
            --do something
        when updating then
            --do something
    end case;
end;
```